# Commutative Diagram and Essential Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have a question about commutative diagram.

[image]

is a commutative diagram of right R-modules and right R-module homomorphisms. Suppose that f and g
are isomorphisms, and also rows are exact. I want to show  if $\phi'(M) < M_2$ is an essential extension, then $h$ must be injective.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you understand? What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Since $M_2$ is an essential extension of $\phi'(M)$, to show $\ker h=\{0\}$, you only have to show that $\phi'(M)\cap \ker h=\{0\}$, i.e. that for all $m\in M$,
$$h\bigl(\phi'(m)\bigr)=0\implies \phi'(m)=0.$$
Set $n=g(m)$ and do some diagram hunting.

*Some more details*. Here's how you can start a-hunting:

As the right square is commutative, you can check that $\psi'(n)=0$, hence, as the bottom row is exact, there exists $n_1\in N_1$ such that $n=\psi(n_1)$. Now $f$ is an isomorphism, so there's a unique $m_1\in M_1$ such that $f(m_1)=n_1$. What can you say about $\phi(m_1)$, given that $g$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Can you help a little more? I am very new to this subject.

Comment: @newy: I've added some details. Please take a look.

Comment: let $\phi(m_1) = m$. Since g is isomorphism, $g(\phi(m_1)) = n $ where $n\in N$. then?